# How to update data view automatically in Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm getting start with Play Framework, however it does not have any decent guide to teach what I wanna do.
I have a service that get Memory and disk statistics, I'd like to load/call this service automatically and pass the values from the controller to the view.

Anyone could provide me any tutorial or tips?

Answer (score 1):

So many recipes for that meal! When you say automatically, I am assuming you mean without user interaction. So your web page will need a way to initiate that update, probably via a javascript timer or more old-fashionedly via [http meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh). In the case of the javascript timer (perhaps [setTimeOut or setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp), each time it "fires" you would use an ajax call to your controller API which would return the data in JSON which you then insert into your page. Pseudo javascript code:

```
on timer event ->
  ajax.GET '/api/monitor' (data) ->
    if data.success
      update $("#results") with data.statistics
```

A very simple view might just have:

```
@() 
@main() {
  <script src="your javascript.js" type="text/javascript">></script>
  <div id="results">
  </div>
}
```

and a controller method to talk to, along the lines (again pseudocode) of:

```
def apiMonitor = Action {
  Ok(Json.obj(
    "success" -> true, 
    "statistics" -> models.statisticsMethod()
  ))
}
```

In this case your play view would be a simple container, and the front end work is not really done in the template.

Using the refresh method, your controller could return a view each time, controller Scala pseudocode:

```
def apiMonitor = Action {
  Ok(view.html.monitor(models.statisticsMethod()
}
```

and a view to format:

```
@(statistics:List[Statistic])
@main() { <!-- where main generates something with the meta refresh in -->
  <table>
    <tbody>
      @statistics.map { statistic =>
        <tr><td>@detail.attribute1</td><td><@detail.attribute2</td></tr>
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
 }
```

There are lots of ways to design such things. The above is incomplete but covers some points you might need.  A very useful place to work from is one of the templates on the [LightBend Website](https://www.lightbend.com/activator/templates) where there is working code to play with.